# Do I need a degree for the Express Entry Program in Canada

Tags: immigration, canada, express-entry

Is it feasible getting a permanent permit for Canada without a degree?

Considering I would have a couple of years of experience and required field, and having the highest scores in IELTS?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you filled out a [Skilled Immigrants Express Entry profile](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/profile.asp) to determine your eligibility?

Comment: While having a degree is not a requirement to apply for permanent residence for Canada, it can certainly boost up your Express Entry profile or improve your permanent residence file (if applying through any other means). Not posting this as an answer because the permanent residence requirements vary from province to province.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it feasible getting a permanent permit for Canada without a degree?

Well education is a high scoring area, so you need to make up those points in other areas. You can see your score by creating a free profile http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/profile.asp then look here for the scores required in the past to be "drawn" (invited to apply) http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/rounds.asp

One way to get more than enough points is to get 600 from a Provincial Nomination as even with a basic degree, it may not be possible to get drawn. For example, I have a bachelors degree and I would not have been drawn without a provincial nomination.

Note that the Provincial Nomination programs have their own criteria which may also heavily weight education. For example, the [Nova Scotia program](http://novascotiaimmigration.com/wp-content/uploads/AppGuide-NSNP-NSDEE-English.pdf) requires a minimum of 67/100 points and they award just 5 points for a high school education and 21 for a bachelors, out of a maximum of 25 for education. With only 2 years experience, you will lose another 4 points there. So you can only afford to lose another 9 points in other areas, which is a very tall order unfortunately.